# Where to go for news in Esperanto?

Tags: culture

I was discussing the situation in Venezuela in the chat about Kernpunkto today, and I was wondering where I could get reasonably up to date information about world news in Esperanto. 
I read Kontakto, Revuo Esperanto and sometimes Monato and Libera Folio. I'd like a source that focuses on the world outside of Esperanto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This website has a collection of news sources in Esperanto:

http://esperanto.net/eo/novajoj-en-esperanto/

Some picks from that site that aren’t about Esperanto itself:

- [El popola ĉinio](http://www.espero.com.cn/) – Mostly news and information about China
- [Le Monde diplomatique](https://eo.mondediplo.com/) – Translation of a famous French newspaper
- [Pola RetRadio](http://pola-retradio.org/novajoj-2/) – News from Poland
- [Global Voices](https://eo.globalvoices.org/) – Translation of Global Voices into Esperanto
- [Scienca Revuo](https://aktuale.scienca-revuo.info/category/sciencoj/) – Scientific news in Esperanto
- https://www.esperanto.blog/

There is also of course the community-edited news site [Vikinovaĵoj](https://eo.wikinews.org/wiki/%C4%88efpa%C4%9Do).

Comment: Estas ankorau la Unesko-ĵurnalo!

Comment: Vere estas multe pli ol mi pensis, dankon!

Answer (score 4):

You may try https://eo.mondediplo.com which is the Esperanto version of the French newspaper "Le monde Diplomatique". It mostly deals with international news.

Answer (score 0):

Globobs.com can be a solution as this website translate into esperanto all newspapers from around the world. it looks like they cover all countries as i  managed to read news from papua new guinea, botswana and kazakstan. so I guess you would easily find news about Venezuela.

Comment: https://globobs.com/